# Is it possible to perform negative binomial regression with known theta?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, dispersion

Is it possible to perform negative binomial regression (in python, R) where you can supply a known value of theta? Say I want to compare different negative binomial regression models, the changing estimate of theta penalises the models differently. If I wanted to fix theta to a set constant is this possible?

EDIT:
This is the R `glm.nb` definition of theta, which is the size parameter, or $r$ in the following pmf of the negative binomial distribution (Polya):

$$f(k;r,p) = P(X=k) = \frac{\Gamma (k+r)}{k!\Gamma (r)}(1-p)^{r}p^{k}.$$

Comment: What is theta in your parametrization? It would help if you wrote out the likelihood with your parametrization

Comment: @TyrelStokes thanks for replying, hopefully my edit will clear up your question.

Comment: Possible, yes (=e.g. modify the glm.nb code yourself), but I don't think there's an implementation that someone has created. I suspect that's because it's not an obvious thing to do - when one has some idea of what theta is (it seems hard to imagine applicatons where one would know exactly), a Bayesian approach seems more natural. For a Bayesian approach e.g. rstanarm or brms might do the job.